# How Do I Compare 2 Records In The Same Table with Wildcard?

Tags: mysql, magento, compare, records

I need to compare records in the same mysql magento table. Is there a way to compare 2 records in the same table, by comparing the url_key to the url? I posted the information below that coresponds to what I'm looking for.

I'm hoping this will help out others who work on Magento's Database as well, as I have posted my 2 previous queries as to how I compared 2 mysql tables to make sure the records were created for categories in magento. I have found that Magento will fail to run flat file reindexing if url-keys and urls do not match. I have ran a few checks to make sure that my url's are correct in both my catalog_category_entity_varchar table as well as my core_url_rewrite table. I intially ran:

SELECT * 
FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` c2t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `core_url_rewrite` c 
    WHERE c.category_id = c2t.entity_id
)

to make sure all of our categories are also entered into core_url rewrite. Then I ran another query to make sure that all of the urls in both tables matched with:

SELECT * 
FROM `core_url_rewrite` c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` c2t 
    WHERE c2t.`entity_id` = c.`category_id`
    AND c2t.`value` = c.`request_path`
)

Now I would like to run one more query to ensure that the url's on catalog_category_entity_varchar are also correct to it's corresponding url key, but I'm completely stuck on it and have no idea how to write the statement.

Basically the catalog_category_entity_varchar table looks like this:

catalog_category_entity_varchar:

Record 1:
value_id:             68
entity_type_id:      3
attribute_id:        43
store_id:               0
entity_id:             10
value:                shop-by

Record 2:
value_id:             73
entity_type_id:      3
attribute_id:        57
store_id:               0
entity_id:             10
value:                shop-by.html

The entity_id is 10 for both records. The attribute ID for url_key is 43 and for the url ID is 57. I imagine that these are what I'll need to use for to identify what I'm comparing.

So basically I'll need to run a query that will matches the entity id's to each other and then compare's the url-key to the url itslef to make sure that it contains the url key. It will have to strip the .html as well as any other part of the url code since records deeper than first level will look something like catalog/shirts/shop-by.html.

Record 3:
value_id:             637
entity_type_id:      3
attribute_id:        57
store_id:               0
entity_id:             88
value:                catalog/shirts/shop-by.html

Also, there will be records that also contain this URL-Key, but I'm assuming that since the query will be based on it's primary key (entity_id), we won't have to worry about that.

I apologize if I haven't written this in the correct format, as I'm still new to this forum. I appreciate in advance for the help. If there's anything unclear or more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Ah, well, typically here you would phrase it in the form of a question, then if you felt like it you can checkbox "answer my own question" (it's under the "post your question" button) and answer yourself that way. If you type the answer as your question it can't be accepted. So basically, edit your post as a question and then post your answer below.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I rephrased the question above, but when I edit, there's no checkbox to answer my own question like there is when you initially type the question. The 2 sql queries I typed above are what I previously did, but not what I'm researching for now.

Comment: Sorry, the button is now underneath me, after "Know someone who can answer?". It's the black-gray button that says "Answer Your Question" ;D. Edit your question, then once you're done you can answer it from here

Comment: Maybe I'm just really confused. I see what you're talking about, but What would I answer the question with if I don't know the answer? LOL

Comment: I think it's me that's confused, I saw your question after rereading slowly. Looked like you had already figured it out. Seems like you're heading in the right direction, although I'm not great with queries. I might be able to show you how to do it through Magento's php framework, with some research. You may want to play around in edit mode, check out the edit help and question posting guides to restructure your question so it stands out more :D

Comment: Now I got what you meant, I too had to re-read slowly. It's my title that wasn't written out in Question format that threw you off. I apologize. Itried to edit the title but it will not allow me too. I meant to edit it and ended up posting another question instead.I am familiar with magento's framework. Problem being is that I have over 475K categories and it would take forever to do it that way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35630/discussion-between-jason-and-n2bh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this query, it's a little ugly but it worked as far as I could tell.

```
SELECT `t1`.*, `t2`.`value` AS `url_path`
FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `t1`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `catalog_category_entity_varchar`.`value`,
        `catalog_category_entity_varchar`.`entity_id`,
        `catalog_category_entity_varchar`.`attribute_id`
    FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar`
) AS `t2`
ON `t1`.`entity_id`=`t2`.`entity_id`
WHERE `t1`.`attribute_id` = 43
AND `t2`.`attribute_id` = 57
AND `t1`.`value` != `t2`.`value`
```

Comment: Fantastic job, I greatly appreciate the time you spent writting out this code for me. It's helping me to get a better undestanding of how MySQL works. Although, I do need this outcome too (It worked out well I would say) I need the exact opossite. This code gave me all the matching url_keys and url's. I need to know which ones don't match as those are the ones that present the error and need to be fixed. How can I change this code to get the exact opposite to echo?

Comment: Added last AND where statement for you. Without it, it should return all records, matching and not.

Comment: Somehow, It's still pulling all the information. Out of almost 500K records, there is one record that does not match, which I can't seem to find that's causing a reindex error in my CMS. I also tried to change != to the older version <> which also pulled all the records except the mismatched record.

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that, either none of your records match or there's a problem in your query. The `AND t1.value != t2.value` explicitly corrects the the query to find all that url_key != url_path. If it's not a query issue, it probably has something with .html being added to all your url_path strings.